# compare Clojure maps with bigdecimal and integers values

Tags: clojure, hashmap, bigdecimal

In my REPL :

```
(== 1 1M)
;;=>true
(= {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 1 :b 2})
;;=>true
(= {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 1 :b 3})
;;=>false
(= {:a 1M :b 2M} {:a 1 :b 2})
;;=>false
```

How can I compare these maps so that the result of the last example would return true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make sure that:

1) The maps have the same keys.

2) every value for a key has an equivalent (==) value in both maps.

Here's my first thought, I'm sure it could be made more succint:

```
(defn number-equivalent
  [m1 m2]
  (let [k1 (keys m1)]
    (and (= k1 (keys m2))
          (every? true?
                  (for [k k1]
                    (== (m1 k)
                        (m2 k)))))))
```

Comment: I like this, although I would prefer `(every? #(== (m1 %) (m2 %)) k1)` to the every?/true/for combo.

Answer (score 1):

Compare corresponding values with `==`

```
(defn compare-nums
  [m1 m2]
  (every? (fn [[k v]] (== (get m1 k) v)) m2))
```

---

Note that both maps need to have the same keys. You might want to add a precondition like

```
  {:pre [(= (.keySet m1) (.keySet m2))]} ; ensure both maps have the same keys
```

Comment: FYI I think you have a typo in there somewhere.  every? accepts a predicate, not a two argument function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will work for multiple maps

```
(defn number-equivalent [& ms]
  (->> (apply merge-with == ms)
       (every? (comp true? val))))
```

Comment: If you are aiming for a variadic version, you should prefer leveraging the variadic impl of `==` over creating an intermediate map in memory.

Comment: This won't work correctly for some maps. For example, `(number-equivalent {:a true} {:b true})`

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn map== [a b]
  (and (= (count a) (count b))
    (reduce-kv (fn [_ k va]
                 (or (and (number? va)
                       (let [vb (get b k)]
                         (and (number? vb)
                           (== va vb))))
                   (reduced false)))
      true a)))
```